# MS access AutoNumber prefix not appearing on web page?

Tags: html, jsp, ms-access, odbc

I made a change in my MS access database so when a new record is entered the incremented unique ID would have a prefix. Although it works in MS access, the ID has no prefix when I load my JSP/html page. See images below.

[image]

[image]

Anyone have any idea how to resolve the problem. Or can it not be done? Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: I suspect yyou have added formats to the table, if so, it is not a good idea ( http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/MSAccess/AccessVBAJetSQL/why-you-should-not-add )

Comment: I did Remou. Doesn't display on the UI though, as it does in the database.

Comment: A format on a table is a display. It is not what the table holds, as you can see from the link in my comment. If you want the display on the webpage, you will have to add the format there.